# 80s/90s TV show: girl with strange (robotic?) voice talks to a "Zordon", maybe in a ship of some kind

Tags: story-identification, tv

What is the TV show from the 80s or 90s that had a short haired girl talking in a strange voice, maybe even robotic? It was part of the show, but I can't remember what else the show was about. Maybe she was talking to something like a 'Zordon'... Can't remember.

I just remember her having short hair and having a strange voice at times... Or talking to something that had a strange voice.

Not sure if they were in a ship of some kind.

Comment: Could she freeze time by touching the ends of her index fingers together?

Comment: Zordon is a Power Rangers character...if that helps.

Comment: Zordon was a character in *Power Rangers*, but I don't recall a short haired girl with a strange voice in that show.

Comment: Live-action or cartoon?

Comment: Small Wonder was an 80's show with a short haired girl who talked in a strange voice because she was a robot. There was no talking to ships or anything similar to "Zordon" though.

Comment: Where did you watch it, which country? Was it imported?

Comment: I wish I remembered where it was from. Its one of those rare instances where you saw a movie or a show long ago as a kid, but cant recall what it was called. It might have been a show from somewhere else, and not from America.

Comment: She might have had a Zordon like voice. Kind of robotic....or something she was speaking to that was non visible had a robotic or zordon like voice.

Comment: It was live action

Comment: What was science fiction or fantasy about it?

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible that you are conflating two different 90's TV shows? I can think of two shows that both match parts of what you said, but not all. As they are similar shows, similar tone, and aired around the same time, I wonder if you're just merging the two into one hybrid in your head?

[*Out Of The World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_This_World_%28TV_series%29) (1987-1991)  is a show about a half-alien teenage girl living with her mother on Earth. In particular, she talks to her alien father telepathically through a strange "cube" device:

> Evie is able to communicate with Troy through a special "genetic" communication device known as the "cube", which he gave to her when she turned thirteen. The cube effectively functions as a telephone line to Antareus — it can even be used to leave Troy an "answerphone" message, as seen in the episode "My Little Evie". There are no controls on the cube; Evie simply calls for her father and the cube activates when he answers, deactivating when he "hangs up". Sometimes when Troy uses his powers whilst talking through the cube, a beam of energy is emitted directly from the cube.

Unfortunately, Evie had long blonde hair:

[image: Maureen Flannigan as Evie]

[*Small Wonder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Wonder_%28TV_series%29) (1985-1989) was a TV show about a young girl who was actually a robot, built by her "father", to act human. I don't remember her voice ever changing, though she was a robot so I guess there could have been episodes where she had voice box problems. But she was a young girl with short dark hair:

[image: young girl with short black hair, red and white clothes]

Comment: It wasnt either show (small wonder, or out of the world) unfortunately. Lol...its killing me not knowing what it is. But I appreciate the comments from yall trying to help me figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

I think the show you've been looking for might be 'The Boy from Andromeda'.
There are many scenes that take part on the ship, there's a short haired girl, and the boy talks in a strange, robotic voice.

Answer (score 2):

The Australian TV show ["Halfway Across the Galaxy and Turn Left"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfway_Across_the_Galaxy_and_Turn_Left) (1994) had a short haired girl from the planet Zyrgon.

[image: short red-haired kids]

Comment: The girl had a look with a haircut like the boy Jean Luc Riker from Star Trek Next Generation...but with light brown/blonde hair. It was a short boy cut. http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Chris_Demetral   Kinda like that.

Comment: Jean Luc Riker?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Riker?

Comment: @Ellesedil I learned something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Girl with short hair and robotic voice would fit with "[Spadla z oblakov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spadla_z_oblakov)" a 1978 Czechoslovakian sci-fi TV-series for children. It was aired in the 80's in several countries, with the title translated to "She Came Out of the Blue Sky" in English

[image: short haired girl in orange clothes]

Comment: No. Not the She came out of the blue sky show either. I appreciate all the help everyone has been trying to find it though.

Comment: I remember the haircut looking shirt like Jean Luc Riker's character from Star Trek.....and I remember the voice being weird sounding. Think the hair color was blond or light brown. It wasn't black I dont think.

Answer (score -1):

Zenon Girl of the 21st Century!!!
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should explain how this fits the question, because from just this image it doesn't look like a great match.